# java ObjectOutputStream create csv file with gibberish data

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have over 300 tables which i want to export to CSV files. However i see gibberish data.

I send the tablename and the retrieve the data using jdbctemplate I can see the data but when i export I see gibberish values

> sr1org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMapiEkMÑ=f$LcaseInsensitiveKeystLjava/util/HashMap
>
> sr1org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMapiEkMÑ=f$LcaseInsensitiveKeystLjava/util/HashMap
>
> q~q~q~q~xq~sq~?@wq~sq~q~trivera92q~

Below is the code:

exportData.java

```
public List getTableData(String tableName){
    return  jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT 10");
}
```

To create csv file

```
@Autowired
ExportData exportData;

public void CreateCsvData(){
 
    String tableName = "user_details";
    String folderPath = "/tmp/Data/";

    List data = this.exportData.getTableData(tableName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(folderPath + tableName + ".csv",true);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fis);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            os.writeObject(data.get(i));
            os.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

here is pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

I saw many examples with `resultsetextractor` and `RowMapper` but its difficult to write models for 300 tables.

Sorry my bad; I did iterate over the object forgot to paste it here;

Comment: Ofcourse you will see "gibberish" as you are writing Java objects to a file. You aren't writing a csv. You wold have to iterate the list, retrieve the map and export the values with a separator. This can be done in a `RowCallbackHandler` this would save marshaling all the results first in memory, and then write it. You can then just directly write to the file.

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` doesn't create `CSV`, so there's your problem.

Comment: Sorry I did iterate over the object but forgot to paste it

Comment: @M.Deinum `RowCallbackHandler` i can only do that if i know the Rows before while the query would give me dynamic Rows. I followed the example from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/objectoutputstream_writeobject.htm)

Comment: No you don't. Your understanding is wrong. Regarding your iteration you are iterating over a list of maps (as I mentioned in my first comment). Each row is a map and you are writing that map to the file. You aren't creating a CSV.

Comment: yeah I still dont get it.. how do i map a dynamic object..?